# Почему происходят ошибки "Cannot find symbol" и "incompatible types" при работе с коллекциями?

Tags: java, коллекции

Уже не первый раз сталкиваюсь с проблемой, что компилятор почему-то не видит методы, работающие с коллекциями (по крайней мере с `ArrayList`).

Вот и здесь он мне выдает:

> cannot find symbol method maxPopSearcher()

Но такой метод существует, и он публичный.

Но в моём коде происходит ещё одна ошибка:

> cannot find symbol method get(int)

Еще выдает ошибку `incompatible types`. Я понимаю, что это несовместимость типов, но откуда там взялся тип `CAP#1`? По поиску необнаружения методов коллекций ничего не нашел. Спасибо.

Вот мой код:

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.zip.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Comparator;
 
public class CitiesPrinter {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       
        final String archive = "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/Jvdroid/single-files/_данные_Сбер_Java_20210407090226.zip";
   //     unzip(archive);
        final String unzippedFile = "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/Jvdroid/single-files/city_ru.csv";       
        Path path = Paths.get(unzippedFile);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(path);               
        var fileToZip = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Documents/Jvdroid/single-files/CitiesPrinter");
        try (
            var fos = new FileOutputStream(fileToZip.getAbsolutePath() + ".zip");
            var zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(fos)
        ) {
            zipFile(fileToZip, fileToZip.getName(), zipOut);
        }
        
  
       List<City> cityList = new ArrayList<>();
       
       readFile(path, unzippedFile, cityList);
      
      Comparator<City> comp1 = new Comparator<>() { // добавил первую сортировку с анонимным классом для неучета регистра
          @Override 
    public int compare(City a, City b){
      
     
        return a.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(b.getName());
      
    }
};
      cityList.sort(comp1);
      System.out.println("Сортировка по наименованию:\n" + cityList.toString());
      Comparator<City> comp2 = new CityDistrictComparator().thenComparing(new CityNameComparator());   
      cityList.sort(comp2);
      
      System.out.println("\n\n\n\nСортировка по федеральному округу и наименованию:\n" + cityList.toString()); // добавил разделительное сообщение
             
             System.out.println("Город с максимальным количеством жителей:\n" + cityList.maxPopSearcher().toString());
        
        }
        
        
        
    public static List readFile(Path p, String file, List cities) throws IOException {
          
          Scanner sc = new Scanner(p);
          sc = new Scanner(Paths.get(file));
          sc.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
          
          while(sc.hasNext()) {
              City city = parseCSVLine1(sc.next());
          //    System.out.println(city.toString());
           cities.add(city);
           }
           sc.close();
  
           return cities;
      }
      
  
       public static City maxPopSearcher(List<?> cities) {
            
            int max = 0;
            for (City city : cities) {
                if (city.getPopulation() > city.get(max)) max = cities.indexOf(city);
            }
            return cities.get(max);
       }
                                 
                                 
                                 
      public static City parseCSVLine1(String line) { 
           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
        scanner.useDelimiter(";"); 
        scanner.skip("\\d*"); 
        String name = scanner.next();
        String region = scanner.next();
        String district = scanner.next();
        int population = scanner.nextInt();
        String foundation = null;
        if (scanner.hasNext()) { 
            foundation = scanner.next();
        }
        scanner.close();

        return new City(name, region, district, population, foundation);
    }
   
      public static void unzip(String archivePath) throws IOException { // распаковывает архив
            try {   try (var file = new ZipFile(archivePath)) {
                var entries = file.entries();
                var uncompressedDirectory = new File(file.getName()).getParent() + File.separator;
                while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                    var entry = entries.nextElement();
                    if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                        processDirectory(uncompressedDirectory, entry);
                    } else {
                        processFile(file, uncompressedDirectory, entry);
                    }
                }      
               }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
       
    }
    
    private static void processDirectory(String uncompressedDirectory, ZipEntry entry) { // создает папку из распакованного архива
        var newDirectory = uncompressedDirectory + entry.getName();
        System.out.println("Creating Directory: " + newDirectory);
        var directory = new File(newDirectory);
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    private static void processFile(ZipFile file, String uncompressedDirectory, ZipEntry entry) throws IOException { // создает файл из распакованного архива
        try (
            var is = file.getInputStream(entry);
            var bis = new BufferedInputStream(is)
        ) {
            var uncompressedFileName = uncompressedDirectory + entry.getName();
            try (
                var os = new FileOutputStream(uncompressedFileName);
                var bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os)
            ) {
                while (bis.available() > 0) {
                    bos.write(bis.read());
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Written: " + entry.getName());
    }
    
    private static void zipFile(File fileToZip, String fileName, ZipOutputStream zipOut) throws IOException { 
    if (fileToZip.isHidden()) {
        return;
    }
    if (fileToZip.isDirectory()) {
        if (fileName.endsWith("/")) {
            zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName));
        } else {
            zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName + "/"));
        }
        zipOut.closeEntry();
        var children = fileToZip.listFiles();
        for (File childFile : children) {
            zipFile(childFile, fileName + "/" + childFile.getName(), zipOut);
        }
        return;
    }
    try (var fis = new FileInputStream(fileToZip)) {
        var zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
        zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
        var bytes = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
            zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
        }
    }
}

    
     
    
     
}
 
    class City {
        
        private String name;
        private String region;
        private String district;
        private int population;
        private String foundation;
         
        public City(String n, String r, String d, int p, String f){
            
            name = n;
            region = r;
            district = d;
            population = p;
            foundation = f;
        }
         
         public String getName() {
             return name;
         }
         
         public String getDistrict() {
             return district;
         }
         
         public int getPopulation() {
             return population;
         }
         
        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return ("City{name='" + name + "', region='" + region + "', district='" + district + "', population='" + population + "', foundation='" + foundation + "'}");      
                }
      
                    
    }
    
    class CityDistrictComparator implements Comparator<City> {
        
   @Override // добавил аннотации
    public int compare(City a, City b){
      
        return a.getDistrict().compareTo(b.getDistrict());
    }
}
class CityNameComparator implements Comparator<City> {
   
   @Override
    public int compare(City a, City b){
      
     
        return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
      
    }
}
```

Comment: По невнимательности закинул код с нестатическим вызовом этого статического метода `maxPopSearcher`. Исправил, но проблему это не решило. И еще не видит метод `getPopulation`.

Comment: maxPopSearcher Это метод класса CitiesPrinter, а не City

Comment: Очень плохо отформатирован код.  Много "мусорного" кода, который не относится к проблеме.

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3):

1. Метод `maxPopSearcher` вызывается у списка(!) `cityList`:

```
System.out.println("Город с максимальным количеством жителей:\n" + cityList.maxPopSearcher().toString());
```

вместо того, чтобы передать этот список в метод:

```java
System.out.println("Город с максимальным количеством жителей:\n" + maxPopSearcher(cityList).toString());
```

2. Сам метод `maxPopSearcher` реализован странным образом, начиная от типа входного списка, заканчивая поиском максимума при помощи `List::indexOf`.
   Исправленный вариант:

```java
public static City maxPopSearcher(List<City> cities) {
    return Collections.max(cities, Comparator.comparingInt(City::getPopulation));            
}
```

3. Все компараторы можно переписать, используя лаконичный синтаксис вместо устаревших классов:

- Сравнение городов по названиям:

```java
Comparator<City> comp1 = Comparator.comparing(City::getName, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

- Сравнение городов по району и названию (классы `CityDistrictComparator`, `CityNameComparator` *не нужны*):

```java
Comparator<City> comp2 = Comparator.comparing(City::getDistrict)
                                   .thenComparing(City::getName);
```

---